# Playing a Sound when view loads

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, audio

I have problems with playing sounds on my iPhone programmatically - i don't understand the explanation in Xcode's Documentation about AvAudioPlayer.
Could someone else please give me a code snippet, or better, explain it to me?

*Edit* what I exactly want to do is playing a sound in an infinite loop, starting when the viewdidload, on app exit the music should stop (not playing in background).
It is for a game I am trying to develop

Actually every method i am using is giving back the same error: (log excerpt)

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

*edit end*

Thanks

Comment: what your means? can you want to play some background sound in your Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your error, your path to the sound file is not valid one (NSURL returns nil for not valid paths).

Comment: But how can i fix this? I just imported it with xcode, i dont Unverstand why there is an error...

Comment: Post the line where you are building NSURL

Comment: NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite

[player play];

Comment: Check two things, first check if soundFileURL is nil. If it is, then check if you included background.mp3 in your project and in your target (you should see it somewhere in the list of Project Navigator and it should be checked Target Membership).

Comment: Ok, i cant find it in the Project Navigator... How do i Add it?

Comment: Open Finder, drag&drop it in Project Navigator. XCode will then open new window where you have to check "Copy items into destination..." and Add to targets - project name.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple way to play short sounds that you have added to your bundle:

```
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"somesound" ofType:@"aif"];

SystemSoundID soundID;

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
```

Here is more documentation on [System Sound Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007916)

**Edit**: since you don't want to simply play a short sounds this might be better:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mySound" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite

[player play];
```

See the [AVAudioPlayer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Comment: how do i add sounds to my "bundle"?

Comment: do i have to import some frameworks? or just call it in my view did load?

Comment: and how do i play this in loop? simply use a timer?

Comment: You will need the AudioToolbox.

Comment: okay, it is crashing when the view loads, here is the log:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Comment: this is returning nil `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mySound" ofType:@"mp3"];` sounds like you can't access your sound file.

Comment: i have imported it from my "documents" of my mac through Xcode...
AvAudioplayer gives me the exact same issue...